# Can you use a gerund in past tense to signify that is happening at the same time

Tags: tenses

Ex. "He spoke softly, narrowing his eyes as they adjusted to the light"
"'I'll never agree,' he said lifting his head in defiance

I know gerunds are present tense but it seems like they can be tied to the tense of the verb preceding it to signify things happening simultaneously.

Am I just mistaken.

Comment: Slight nit-pick: The question in the title is phrased positively ("Can I ...") but your final question in the message itself is phrased negatively ("Am I mistaken?"), so it's hard to answer with "yes" or "no" without contradicting at least one of them. Also, you seem to be missing some question marks. :)

Comment: You should avoid the term "gerund" like the plague. There is no such thing as "gerund" in English :) "Narrowing his eyes" is a tenseless clause - we cannot know the time of the situation from this clause alone. We never can, in no possible context. In complex clauses like this, the time of the situation described by the -ing clause can be understood either as the same as that of the situation in the main clause, or preceding that time. The former is the case in your sentence.

Comment: Where is this gerund of which you speak?